# How do I launch an Intent or thread from a Handler?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, handler

I have a client/server application that needs to be able to launch a variety of threads with lifecycles between 10 seconds and 24 hours.   My TCP connection is running in a thread in the background and is working fine but I can’t figure out how to launch the individual threads from inside my handler bound to my TCP thread.  The handler works fine for displaying test string sent by the server but I can’t get Java to accept me launching anything from inside that handler.  I’ve tried an Intend, runOnUIThread and a standard thread, each separately, but it keeps complaining about a static reference to the non-static field.  I understand static variables but not sure what it’s talking about here.  I've added the error messages as comments in my posted code.  Thanks

```
static Handler TCP_handler = new Handler()
{   
    @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    Message.obtain();
    Bundle bundle = msg.getData();          

    switch( msg.what ){
        case 1: // this stuff works fine
                String aResponse1 = bundle.getString("messageStringL1");
            String aResponse2 = bundle.getString("messageStringL2");
            if(aResponse1 != null)
                textViewLineOne.setText(aResponse1);
            if(aResponse2 != null)
                textViewLineTwo.setText(aResponse2);
                break;
            case 2:  
                // Method 1
        // error: “No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope”
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IdleScreen.class);
        // if I take out "MainActivity.this" I get the error “static reference to the non-static method”
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);                 

        // Method 2
        // error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runOnUiThread(Runnable) from the type Activity
                MainActivity.runOnUiThread(IdleScreen); 

                // Method 3 
        // error: “Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field IdleObj.”  
        // If I make my Idleobj static it compiles but the thread never runs
                IdleObj = new IdleScreen();  
            Thread IdleScreenThead = new Thread();
                IdleScreenThead.start();    
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

UPDATE: I removed static and created an object in my TCP class so that the class can see my handler which is located in MainActivity.  I can launch the thread from the handler now but I can’t launch the Intent without a runtime error and NullPointerException; the Intent works fine from a button.  I tried saving the context in MainActivity's onCreate and using that instead of MainActivity.this but get the same crash.  The reason I think I need the Intent to work is that when I launch each of the different threads I can include a new screen (Activity) where the user can use a keyboard or make some sort of selection from a list, etc. Am I on the correct path here or need some new ideas?

// this gives me a NullPointerException if called from TCP_handler but works fine if called from a button.
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IdleScreen.class);
startActivity(i);

Comment: You are defining `Handler TCP_handler` as `static` which means that it doesn't have access to the `this` instance of the outer class (I'm guessing is `MainActivity`).

Comment: You were on the right track. Removing the static designation and creating a MainActivity object in my TCP class allowed me to connect. Still can't use the Intent but that at least I'm getting there.

Answer (score 0):

Static handler is a bad idea, especially if you want to interact with user interface. 
What will you do when application goes into background and destroys all the activities of application?

If needed lifetime object the best way is to create it in the child of [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and override method onCreate() where you can instantiate some object and give it reference to application which extends context class. Also create getter for its object.

When activity started, you can call getApplication() method then cast to your classname of application and get needed object by getter. And you can pass reference to activity using this way. but don't forget to notify that object when onPause of Activity is called - this is means activity will be destroyed soon.

One more - you should specify your application class in your manifest if you use custom 
Application class.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Keeping this thing running 24/7 is a concern of mine. It usually stops after 15 minutes or so but gives me no feedback.  I don't understand most of what you wrote but it gives me a place to start thinking. Anything more you can add would be appreciated.  Thanks